# Is it possible to add app.get() in sails.js project?

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I'm using sails.js v1 in my current project. And I want to add this line of code:

```
   app.get('*', (req, res) => {   
         res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../apply_frontend/FrontEnd/dist/apply-system/index.html')); 
   });
```

Does anyone have an idea about this? Thank you.

Comment: You should have a `config/route.js` file, in there you can add/update your route(s) following the guidelines [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/routes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not use app.get() in sails.js, because sails.js by default provide route file in 
config folder. (https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/routes)

app.get() works only on express.js because we are initializing app variable with express constructor. For that we need to require express npm module which is not needed if you are using sails.js.

```
var express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.get();
```